# Negative Binomial Problem

Tags: statistics, negative-binomial

I found this question while going through a book:

> In a casino game Ruben rolls a die and whenever a one or a six
>   is rolled he receives a token. The game ends when Ruben has
>   received y tokens; he then receives $x, where x is the number of
>   rolls he has made.
>
> (a) The probability of the game ending on the sixth roll is 40/729.
>   Find the value of y.

According to the negative binomial distribution representation, we need to calculate $y$ in $X$ follows $NB(y, 1/3)$. Here is the formula for negative binomial distribution for this quesiton:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
6-1 \\
y-1 \\
\end{pmatrix} (\frac{1}{3})^y(1-\frac{1}{3})^{6-y} = \frac{40}{729}
$$
The first paranthesis above is for the combinations equation. How would one go about solving from this point, or is this the right path to approach this question. How should I find the value of $y$?

Comment: $$
\binom{6-1}{4-1}\left(\frac13\right)^4\left(1-\frac13\right)^{6-4} = \frac{40}{729}.
$$

Comment: How did you get $y = 4$ @Math1000

Comment: I simply computed $$\binom{6-1}{y-1}\left(\frac13\right)^y\left(1-\frac13\right)^{6-y} $$ for $y=0,1,2,\ldots$ until I got the right value :)